# Zookeeper/Chubby -vs- MySql NDB

Tags: java, mysql, replication, database-replication, apache-zookeeper

I have been reading the Paxos paper, the FLP theorem etc. recently and evaluating Apache Zookeeper for a project. I have also been going thru Chubby (Google's distributed locking service) and the various literature on it that is available online. My fundamental usecase for Zookeeper is to implement replication and general coordination for a distributed system.

I was just wondering though, what is the specific advantage that Zookeeper or a Chubby like distributed locking system brings to the table. Basically I am just wondering why I can't just use a MySQL NDB Cluster. I keep hearing that MySQL has a lot of replication issues. I was hoping some with more experience on the subject might shed some light on it.

Thanks in advance..

A simplistic listing of my requirements :

- I have a homogeneous distributed system.
- I need some means of maintaining consistent state across all my nodes.
- My system exposes a service, and interaction with clients will lead to some change in collective state of my system.
- High availability is a goal, thus a node going down must not affect the service.
- I expect the system to service atleast a couple of 1000 req/sec.
- I expect the collective state of the system to be bounded in size (basically inserts/deletes will be transient... but in steady state, i expect lots of updates and reads)

Comment: This question is difficult to answer without knowing more about what you are trying to achieve.  It is quite possible that simple MySQL replication (not even using NDB) could be sufficient for you.

In most database architectures, the key questions to answer are 
1) what is my Recovery Time Objective (ie. how long do I have to recover from primary database crashes)
2) what is my Recovery Point Objective (ie. how much data can I stand to lose in the event of the Primary database crashing)

The tighter your tolerances for these objectives, the more elaborate (and expensive) the solution.

Comment: Thanx martin... I just updated my question with my requirements..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It depends on the kind of data you are managing and the scale and fault tolerance you are going for.

I can answer from the ZooKeeper point of view. Before starting I should mention that ZooKeeper is not a Chubby clone. Specifically it does not do locks directly. It is also designed with different ordering and performance requirements in mind.

In ZooKeeper the entire copy of system state is memory resident. Changes are replicated using an atomic broadcast protocol and synced to disk (using a change journal) by a majority of ZooKeeper servers before being processed. Because of this ZooKeeper has deterministic performance that can tolerate failures as long as a majority of servers are up. Even with a big outage, such as a power failure, as long as a majority of servers come back on line, system state will be preserved. The information stored is ZooKeeper is usually considered the ground truth of the system so such consistency and durability guarantees are very important.

The other things that ZooKeeper gives you have to do with monitoring dynamic coordination state. Ephemeral nodes allow you do to easy failure detection and group membership. The ordering guarantees allow you to do leader election and client side locking. Finally, watches allow you to monitor system state and quickly respond to changes in system state.

So if you need to manage and respond to dynamic configuration, detect failures, elect leaders, etc. ZooKeeper is what you are looking for. If you need to store lots of data or you need a relational model for that data, MySQL is a much better option.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "designed with different ordering and performance requirements in mind" for someone vaguely familiar w/ the Chubby paper?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't elaborate too much, because I only know about Chubby from the paper. One of the things they point out is that Chubby was designed for course grained coordination. For ZooKeeper we wanted to have high enough performance that applications could use it extensively. For that reason we traded synchronous updates for ordered operations.

For example, with Chubby before a write completes all clients are notified of the change. ZooKeeper relaxes this a bit. Change notifications are queued to ZooKeeper clients, when the write completes, but may not be delivered.

Comment: Sorry, the comment limit was too short.

ZooKeeper operations are wait-free. This means that one client cannot block the execution of another clients operation. It also means that we can get a nice execution pipeline going for high throughput. We get write throughput in the range of tens of thousands of ops per second and read throughput of hundreds of thousands. The trade off for the most part is not noticeable to the developer, except for a couple of corner cases that they may need to use the sync() method.

Answer (score 14):

MySQL with Innodb provides a good general purpose solution, and will probably keep up with your performance requirements quite easily on not-too-expensive hardware.  It can easily handle many thousands of updates per second on a dual quad-core box with decent disks.  The built-in asynchronous replication will get you most of the way there for your availability requirements - but you might lose a few seconds' worth of data if the primary fails.  Some of this lost data might be recoverable when the primary is repaired, or might be recoverable from your application logs:  whether you can tolerate this is dependent on how your system works.   A less lossy - but slower - alternative is to use MySQL Innodb with shared disk between Primary and Failover units:  in this case, the Failover unit will take over the disk when the Primary fails with no loss of data -- as long as the Primary did not have some kind of disk catastrophe.  If shared disk is not available, DRBD can be used to simulate this by synchronously copying disk blocks to the Failover unit as they are written: this might have an impact on performance.

Using Innodb and one of the replication solutions above will get your data copied to your Failover unit, which is a large part of the recovery problem solved, but extra glue is required to reconfigure your system to bring the Failover unit on-line.   This is usually performed with a cluster system like RHCS or Pacemaker or Heartbeat (on Linux) or the MS Cluster stuff for Windows.   These systems are toolkits, and you are left to get your hands dirty building them into a solution that will fit your environment.  However, for all of these systems there is a brief outage period while the system notices that the Primary has failed, and reconfigures the system to use the Failover unit.  This might be tens of seconds:  trying to reduce this can make your failure detection system too sensitive, and you might find your system being failed over unnecessarily.

Moving up, MySQL NDB is intended to reduce the time to recovery, and to some extent help scale up your database for improved performance.  However, MySQL NDB has a quite narrow range of applicability.  The system maps a relational database on to a distributed hash table, and so for complex queries involving multiple joins across tables, there is quite a bit of traffic between the MySQL component and the storage components (the NDB nodes) making complex queries run slow.  However, queries that fit well run very fast indeed.   I have looked at this product a few times, but my existing databases have been too complicated to fit well and would require a lot of redesign to get good performance.  However, if you are at the design stage of a new system, NDB would work well if you can bear its constraints in mind as you go.  Also, you might find that you need quite a few machines to provide a good NDB solution: a couple of MySQL nodes plus 3 or more NDB nodes - although the MySQL and NDB nodes can co-exist if your performance needs are not too extreme.

Even MySQL NDB cannot cope with total site loss - fire at the data centre, admin error, etc.  In this case, you usually need another replication stream running to a DR site.  This will normally be done asynchronously so that connectivity blips on the inter-site link does not stall your whole database.  This is provided with NDB's Geographic replication option (in the paid-for telco version), but I think MySQL 5.1 and above can provide this natively.

Unfortunately, I know little about Zookeeper and Chubby.  Hopefully someone else can pick up these aspects.

Comment: That was a really informative post.. thanx.
Hoping someone with Zookeeper experience would share their thoughts as well..